# CSS Make user text selection vertically in table

Tags: html, css, highlight, textselection

I want to create a table, but I want the user to be able to select the columns first and then the second column and so on (instead of the way of selecting the rows first).

| *First* | Second |
| --- | --- |
| *This is the first message* | This is the second message |
| *This is the first message in the second row* | This is the second message in the second row |

(Only the things that are italic should be selected by the user at once and the same for the other one)

And so that when I select "First" and end the selection with "*This is the first message in the second row*" it should only select "*This is the first message*" with it and not "Second" and "*This is the second message*" with it.

---

I've tried `user-select: none;`, but this only works if I only want the user to be able to select one column.

Comment: Why is the user selecting everything in the one column?

Comment: @NathanielFlick The user should do that and the selection is on a row-basis. I want that as I want the user to be able to copy the collums and paste it directly as if the lines between the rows do not exist.

Comment: Have you thought about adding more advanced features to your tables using Datatables JS? https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: @Nathaniel Flick No, as I do not need all of these features.

Comment: You don't have to use all the features but I'll bet it has what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by nesting tables:

```css
table{
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>First</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is the first message</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is the first message in the second row</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Second</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is the second message</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is the second message in the second row</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes (and thanks), but unfortunately this does not work exactly like a table would. (And I need this behaviour of the same height of the cells that are next to another).

Comment: @QuickWrite What do you mean by "this does not work exactly like a table would"?

Comment: When I create a `<td>` Element and I am inserting content into this element it calculates the height. And this height is transferred to all of the other elements in the `<tr>`-tag. But this is unfortunately not here as if I do `This is the first <br> message` the td does not have the same height as the td with the content of `This is the second message`
(And I am sorry that my question was not clear)

Comment: I've marked this question as "accepted" as this was the best (and unfortunately) only answer that tried something that maybe could help others.